# Enable CheckBoxList using CheckBox? - ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am having trouble with my code, I was able to implement it using code behind but it was not good as I have sliding panel (using jQuery) which were interfered with on post back.

The CheckBoxList is disabled by default with no auto postback.

I want the CheckBoxList to become enables if the CheckBox is checked.

Currently, I have this code:

```
$("#BizAppsCheckBox").click(function () {
        if (this.checked)
            $('#BizAppsCheckBoxList').removeAttr('disabled');
        else
            $('#BizAppsCheckBoxList').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
```

How can I fix this issue?

Best working solution for me, thanks to the answers:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
if ($("#BizAppsCheckBox").prop('checked') == false) {
                $('#BizAppsCheckBoxList *').prop('disabled', true);
            }
            else {
                $('#BizAppsCheckBoxList *').prop('disabled', false);
            }

$("#BizAppsCheckBox").click(function () {
                if (this.checked)
                    $('#BizAppsCheckBoxList *').prop('disabled', false);
                else
                    $('#BizAppsCheckBoxList *').prop('disabled', true) &
                $('#BizAppsCheckBoxList *').prop('checked', false);
            });
});
```

Comment: I tried all the solution but none are working for me..

Comment: How are you disabling the CheckBoxList to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

You should use the ClientID cuz asp.net does provide different ID ( when under container)

```
$("#<%=BizAppsCheckBox.ClientID%> ").click(function () {
                if (this.checked)
                    $('#<%=BizAppsCheckBoxList.ClientID%>').prop('disabled',false);
                else
                    $('#<%=BizAppsCheckBoxList.ClientID%>').prop('disabled', true);
            });
```

## edit

```
 $("#<%=BizAppsCheckBox.ClientID%>").click(function () {
                if (this.checked)
                    $('#<%=BizAppsCheckBoxList.ClientID%> *').prop('disabled', false);
                else
                    $('#<%=BizAppsCheckBoxList.ClientID%> *').prop('disabled', true);
            });
```

Comment: please have a look above

Comment: thanks, your code works really good now but i still have one problem - when the page first loads the checkboxlist is enabled, if i do set it to "enabled=false". That messes up with the search results by not including the items clicked in the checkbox list. Can you help me with that please?

Answer (score 1):

Use `prop` instead of `attr`, if [**ClientIDMode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) is not static then use `ClientID` of server controls

```
$("#<%= BizAppsCheckBox.ClientID %>").click(function () {
      if (this.checked)
           $('#<%= BizAppsCheckBoxList.ClientID %>').prop('disabled', true);
      else
           $('#<%= BizAppsCheckBoxList.ClientID %>').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Comment: What is not working, can you please explain? do you get click event?

Answer (score 1):

this will do the trick

```
$("#<%=BizAppsCheckBox.ClientID%>").click(function () {       
       $('#<%=BizAppsCheckBoxList.ClientID%>').prop('disabled',!this.checked);
});
```

or

```
$("#BizAppsCheckBox").click(function () {
         $('#BizAppsCheckBoxList').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

try using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("document").on("click","#<%=BizAppsCheckBox.ClientID%>",function(){
         $('#<%=BizAppsCheckBoxList.ClientID%>').prop('disabled',!this.checked);
});
```